# Azure Logic App HTTP Listener

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-http/#using-the-http-listener-in-your-logic-app says that after creating an HTTP Listener, I need to:

1. Create a new Logic App.
2. Open “Triggers and Actions” to open the Logic Apps Designer and configure your flow. The HTTP Listener is listed in the gallery. Select it.
3. You can now set the HTTP Method and the relative URL on which you require the listener to trigger the flow

I have followed the steps religiously yet no matter what I do, I see something different from the tutorial!  In particular, I see something about `Double cilck here to configure this API App`  [image]

I have looked at many different tutorials online and they all have the same instructions with the same example photo.  None of them appear to see what I see.  Double clicking just takes me to the APIAPP blade where I can see an API definition but I don't see any way to add a new API endpoint.  It appears that I have a PUT, DELETE and POST endpoint created for me (all defaults I presume) and I can download a Swagger file but nothing about how I can add a new GET or POST trigger.

I'm hoping someone can tell me what it is that I am doing wrong or missing here.  Perhaps my API App is missing some critical piece of configuration information before it can be used in a Logic App?  I followed the directions to the letter as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the missing piece of the puzzle was to click on the arrow underneath the "Double click here" text.  I had assumed that the arrow was the same as double clicking.

Comment: If it doesn't come back I'll delete the link.